# Twitter Bootstrap: drop-down menu class not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm trying to view the result of the following sample
code from the O'Reilly book on Bootstrap. I have seen
several other posts on this topic but none seemed to
explain the following [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/ffbwam70/1/). It seems as though
the dropdown-menu class is preventing the unordered list from
showing up despite I have included the bootstrap css and js files.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The following code example from the book also [does not work in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffbwam70/2/)
(the button shows up but when I click no menu appears):

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid. Make sure you have included jquery as the dropdown-menu requires it to work.

Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery UI (In case you want it)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is another valid drop down to test.

```
 <div class="btn-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default">Action</button> <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added JQuery Core and now my last example as well as the example you posted work. However, as this [JSFiddle snippet demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/ffbwam70/3/), the first batch of code still does not work, not even if I add JQuery UI to the list of included eternal resources. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the example they give is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but how can it be fixed?

Comment: If you're looking for a drop down menu then the code in my answer produces one as long as jquery 2+ and Bootstrap 3+ are included.